# Notify item changed is not working in recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, notifyitemchanged

My code adds items to favorites in SQLite:

```java
if (productsArray.get(getAdapterPosition()).isFavorite()){
    productsArray.get(getAdapterPosition()).setFavorite(false);
}else{
    productsArray.get(getAdapterPosition()).setFavorite(true);
}
notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition());
```

My "notify item changed" function is not working for view. In my onBindViewHolder(), the favorite image is not changing

```java
if (products.isFavorite()){
    holder.fav_img.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_on));
}else{
    fav_img.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_off));
}
```

Comment: did you tried putting a breakpoint inside onBindViewHolder() and see if its going in it or not when you add items to favorite.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.